# Use variable to access array results in undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting several arrays returned from a `GET` reponse, which I need to access. Since their names can change based on the request, I have a variable specifing which array to use.

However I always get undefined. See this:

```
            console.log(current); // trips_out_201702
            console.log(theResponse.current); // undefined
            console.log(theResponse.trips_out_201702); // this works
```

How can I make `theResponse.current` work such that it returns what `current` actually stands for? Why do I get undefined there?

Answer (score 1):

When the property key in an object is a variable you can use the square bracket notation to access that property.

```
  console.log(theResponse[current]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

when acessing with dynamic attribute You should do as

**theResponse[current]** not **theResponse.current**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get array value using object's way.
You should try this one instant `variable['keyName']`
Good Luck!